# reporting services, have two reports in rdl

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, rdl

I have a SSRS 2008 report that shows some information based on a start date.

I would now like to add another instance of the report to the same rdl, with a different start date.

How can I add a second instance of the same report to the rdl file?  There doesn't seem to be a way to copy and paste it in.

The dataset is the same, just a parameter value changes, but both need to be shown on the same report.

Comment: Why aren't you passing start date in as a parameter?

Comment: @PaulAlanTaylor I am, but I need two reports in the one rdl, which are the same report, with different start dates.  The parameters bit seems fine, it's how to have the two reports on the one rdl that I don't see how to do.

Answer (score 2):

Your question sounds a little confusing, because you're talking of "a report in an rdl", but an RDL *is* a report. What you should probably be looking into is [creating a subreport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160348%28v=sql.100%29.aspx). You can create a "master" report that holds the subreport either exactly twice (2 times) or in a list (n times).

The business case around your start date will determine which option is best for you. If you just have a master report with merely two subreports right below eachother, you can hard-code the parameter "start date" for both subreports. In this case you don't even need a data-set in the master report.

If you need or want to be more flexible use the other option with the subreport in a list. You could create a dataset with a column "start date" and bind that to the parameter for the subreport. This way it's easy to extend the setup to show the report three, four, or n times.

In any case, either option allows you to [minimize copy/paste action](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRY), which is a good thing.

Comment: Okay, look at an RDL with a report.  The report is contained in a box.  I just want two boxes, therefore two reports.  I don't want a per-row sub-report, though a rub-report that is only shown once, after the other report, would be fine.  Can that be done?  Edit: Actually, the 2nd of your options could work.  How could I set up the master report so that it did not show anything other than the sub-reports?  And would I need to bind that master report to another dataset that contained my two start dates?

Comment: I've updated the answer to clarify how to combine a dataset (if needed) and the parameter. Either way, best advice for you now would be to just go out and try it.